# Раздельные логи микросервисов

Tags: c#, .net

У меня микросервисное API на dotnet core 2.2
Изучал и брал в пример: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Как сделать такие раздельные логи для каждого сервиса?
[image: логи]

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам клонировать тот репозитории, разбираться как его запустить, искать чем они там логгируют и пробовать воспроизводить вашу проблему только чтобы вам помочь?

Comment: Нет. Библиотека явно популярная. Для логгирования там используют Serilog. Но в нем нет такой фичи, он логгирует все в монолит. Если не знаете, что это, то проходите мимо вопроса и все

Comment: Я пытался вам пояснить, что ваш вопрос слишком общий, что вам надо больше времени уделить качеству вопроса, добавить информацию о том, что там за логгер, как он работает, как он связан с другими микросервисами, как вы сами пытались его настроить и прочее. Но раз вы считаете, что ваш вопрос и так отлично написан, никаких проблем, я просто поставлю минус и дальше пойду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eShopOnContainers - это пример, хоть и сложный. Он не решает все проблемы - он показывает как разрабатывать микросервисы, но не полностью показывает как их хостить и мониторить.

Судя по всему, на скрине результат запуска `docker-compose up`. Compose редиректит консольный вывод всех контейнеров в свое окно, приписывая имя сервиса в начале строки.

В реальности у каждого микросервиса - свой output, и если вы захостите тот же самый проект в каком-нибудь Azure AKS, то на выходе вы получите логи в таблице, с отдельной колонкой - именем сервиса, по которому сможете отфильтровать.

Если собирать логи не из консоли, а напрямую через sink в serilog - опять же, решается конфигурацией, а не кодом сервиса. Ведь вас будет интересовать не только имя сервиса, но, например, и версия. Или еще что-то, специфическое для вашего деплоймента. Вы можете дописать уникальные свойства для каждого деплоймента через serilog:enrich:with-property.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Действительно тот ответ, что мне нужен. Меня заинтересовал этот проект ибо грамотно написан и документация с data flow. А так, буду делать деплой на свой сервер, Azure не нужен. А на счет логов, то буду использовать Seq для просмотра, как по мне он очень удобен и Serilog для логгирования

Comment: @Atantares на свой сервер микросервисы лучше вообще не деплоить (только что-то мелкое, на одну машину и в виде compose). Что-то посложнее потребует нормального оркестратора (а он сейчас один, k8s), а оркестраторы очень тяжело деплоить не в облако - слишком уж они полагаются на облачную инфраструктуру. Например, k8s не умеет публиковать серверы наружу из кластера на определенном порту (тип сервиса LoadBalancer) - что уже мешает нормально деплоить на него приложения.

Comment: Хмм... А это уже интересно, учту. Буду смотреть.